# How to bind a List<DateTime> to a DataGridView/ListBox .NET C#

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, datetime, generic-list

I have a List that I want to bind to a DataGridView in a windows forms app.
however, I cannot for the life of me find the DataPropertyName I need to show what I want. I have had similar problems with binding this list to a listbox.

what i really want is to show .ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"), or certainly more than the standard 'date' part of the datetime - do i need to add a property of my own?

```
public partial class DateTime{
  public string myFormat{
    get{return this.ToString("dddd dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");}
  }
}
```

or some such?

thanks

nat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a DataGridView, [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s(v=VS.100).aspx) explains how to format dates.